# Batch script, how to cut the portion of a line in a file from the desired word onwards

Tags: batch-file

I have a 2 lines in a file(input.txt) as below,

```
D:\myfolder\main.c:1:INT ABCD 1234 abc();
D:\myfolder\main.c:3:CHAR EFGH 5678 xyz();
```

Expected output to file (D:\F1\output.txt) should be

```
INT ABCD 1234 abc();
CHAR EFGH 5678 xyz();
```

Note: need to copy the part of the line starts with VARIABLE(int or char or any other variables) TO THE END OF THR LINE until ; (semicolon) to output file

Comment: If the filename will always have a drive letter (containing a colon) and it will be followed by a number surrounded by colons (two more colons, then you could use `for /F "tokens=4 delims=:" %%F in (input.txt) do echo %%F`

Comment: This is only half of a question, providing the rest of the task would make answering this easier. It is my belief that your two line file, `input.txt`, is the result of a `findstr` query using at least the `/N` option and a wildcard for the search files. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61118959/edit) to provide the code you have used to produce `input.txt`.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah It would be better to use `for /F "tokens=3* delims=:" %%I in (input.txt) do echo(%%J` to really output always everything after third (series of) colon(s) of a line even on rest of the line contains also a colon.

Comment: There is no guarantee that the file path at the beginning of each line always includes a letter followed by a colon. We would know that from the OP providing more information regarding the criteria passed to `findstr`. If the search file(s) included a drive letter and colon, then one will be included, if it didn't, then one will not!

Comment: @Mofi Good point - I should have thought of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is not effort from the OP to solve or explain better the problem, then there is no effort from my part to explain the code...

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

(for /F "delims=" %%a in (input.txt) do (
   set "in=%%a"
   set "out="
   for %%v in (INT CHAR) do if not defined out call :GetVar "!in:%%v=" "%%v!"
   echo !out!
)) > D:\F1\output.txt
goto :EOF

:GetVar
set "out=%~2"
exit /B
```

**EDIT**: Another simpler method:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

(for /F "delims=" %%a in (input.txt) do (
   set "in=%%a"
   for %%v in (INT CHAR) do if "!in:*%%v=%%v!" neq "!in!" set "out=!in:*%%v=%%v!"
   echo !out!
)) > D:\F1\output.txt
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks much. the 2nd method worked fine.
Please provide the way to save the contents of the output.txt during every execution of this script.
Actual data in output.txt should remain as is and should not be interrupted and the latest output should be pasted at the end of the page ( means last line in output.txt)
For now, new output is over writing the old output. it should not happend that way. Please help.